# Replace character except between pattern using grep -o or sed (or others)

Tags: awk, sed, grep

In the following file I want to replace all the `;` by `,` with the exception that, when there is a string (delimited with two `"`), it should not replace the `;` inside it.

Example:
Input

```
A;B;C;D
5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f;5cc0714b9b69581f14f6428e;1;"5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f;16a4fba8d13";xpto;
5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285;5cc0723b9b69581f14f64294;2;"5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285;16a4fbe3855";xpto;
5cc072579b69581f14f6428a;5cc072579b69581f14f64299;3;"5cc072579b69581f14f6428a;16a4fbea632";xpto;
```

output

```
A,B,C,D
5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f,5cc0714b9b69581f14f6428e,1,"5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f;16a4fba8d13",xpto,
5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285,5cc0723b9b69581f14f64294,2,"5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285;16a4fbe3855",xpto,
5cc072579b69581f14f6428a,5cc072579b69581f14f64299,3,"5cc072579b69581f14f6428a;16a4fbea632",xpto,
```

For sed I have: `sed 's/;/,/g' input.txt > output.txt` but this would replace everything.

The regex for the `"` delimited string: `\".*;.*\"` .

(A regex for hexadecimal would be better -- something like: `[0-9a-fA-F]+`)

**My problem is combining it all to make a grep -o / sed that replaces everything except for that pattern.**

The file size is in the order of two digit Gb  (max 99Gb), so [performance is important. Relevant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303044/when-to-use-grep-less-awk-sed).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is a two pass approach acceptable ?

Comment: yes. as long as it works and is fast I take everything (beggars can't be choosers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get correctly your requirements, one option would be to make a three pass thing.

From your comment about hex, I'll consider nothing like # will come in the input so you can do (using GNU sed) :

```
sed -E 's/("[^"]+);([^"]+")/\1#\2/g' original > transformed
sed -i 's/;/,/g' transformed
sed -i 's/#/;/g' transformed
```

The idea being to replace the `;` when within quotes by something else and write it to a new file, then replace all `;` by `,` and then set back the `;` in place within the same file (`-i` flag of sed).

The three pass can be combined in a single command with

```
sed -E 's/("[^"]+);([^"]+")/\1#\2/g;s/;/,/g;s/#/;/g' original > transformed
```

That said, there's probably a bunch of csv parser witch already handle quoted fields that you can probably use in the final use case as I bet this is just an intermediary step for something else later in the chain.

From [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)'s comment: if you do it in one pass, you can use `\n` as replacement separator as there can't be a newline in the text considered line by line.

Comment: very well thought. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you can't do that in one sed pass.

Comment: @Tensibai It's not working. The # is not being replaced in your first sed. even adding /g at the end, nothing is replaced

Comment: @stevesliva you mean the 3 commands in one sed call, yep it's doable but I had wish to keep it simple, the overhead is not that much IIRC but I may be wrong

Comment: @Tensibai I found it. Needs -E and its \1 instead of $1. ```sed -E 's/("[^"]+);([^"]+")/\1#\2/g' PhaseChanges_orig.csv > transformed```

Comment: Aww, I was wondering why I couldn't repro, reading your comment I found it, I've an alias :( #shame

Comment: I mention that it doesn't require several passes mostly to make it clear that sed doesn't require it here.  There are reasons to *have to* pipe sed to sed... but sequential manipulations within a single line isn't one of them.  That said, if you have intermediate files, it can make debug easier, and that's a valid reason to separate them.

Comment: @stevesliva I've added the alternative to be complete

Comment: @JonyD We have edited at the same time and yours had been automatically rejected, sorry about it :) I hope I didn't miss a point

Comment: If you did it all in a single call to sed then you could use `\n` instead of `#` as the temp char since you KNOW there can't be newlines in the data (unlike `#` which you're just HOPING won't be in the data). You should mention your solution requires GNU sed for various constructs it uses.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is for doing simple `s/old/new` on individual strings. `grep` is for doing `g/re/p`. You're not trying to do either of those tasks so you shouldn't be considering either of those tools. That leaves the other standard UNIX tool for manipulating text - `awk`.

You have a `;`-separated CSV that you want to make `,`-separated. That's simply:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^;]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
A,B,C,D
5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f,5cc0714b9b69581f14f6428e,1,"5cc0714b9b69581f14f6427f;16a4fba8d13",xpto,
5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285,5cc0723b9b69581f14f64294,2,"5cc0723b9b69581f14f64285;16a4fbe3855",xpto,
5cc072579b69581f14f6428a,5cc072579b69581f14f64299,3,"5cc072579b69581f14f6428a;16a4fbea632",xpto,
```

The above uses GNU awk for FPAT. See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001) for more details on parsing CSVs with awk.

Comment: I should have bet you'll have a better approach than my naive one :)

Comment: ```g/re/p``` stands for "global regular expression print" , "globally search a regular expression and print".

Comment: @JonyD yes, that's correct - it's the `ed` command line `g/re/p` where `re` means Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1\n/;ta;y/;/,/;y/\n/;/' file
```

Replace `;`'s inside double quotes with newlines, transpose `;`'s to `,`'s and then transpose newlines to `;`'s.